# Python: TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Tags: python, opencv, typeerror

So I am really stuck on this error. I've looked at basically every source and forum online with the same error addressed, but can't figure out what's wrong with my specific problem.

Here is my code. I'm essentially trying to resize the 2 images, saved under paths named `cut_path_1` and `cut_path_2`:

```
dim = (300, 400)
cut1 = cv.resize(cut_path_1, dim, interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)
cut2 = cv.resize(cut_path_2, dim, interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)
```

Here's what I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    cut1 = cv.resize(cut_path_1, dim, interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)
    TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

Comment: What would help is a self-contained example (please read [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Hi Elise, before going through every forum online it is often best to read the package documentation to check if you are using the function correctly. The first argument of the function `resize` should not be an image path but the image object itself. Read the image from its path using the `imread` function. Coding is hard.